# After upgrade for Android Studio 2.1.1 Error:(30, 13)

Tags: android, gradle

Today, after upgrade *Android Studio* from *2.1.0* to *2.1.1*, when compiling gradle, the error shows:

> Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.4.0

How to solve?

**build.gradle:**

```js
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://ksoap2-android.googlecode.com/svn/m2-repo' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://ksoap2-android.googlecode.com/svn/m2-repo' }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**app/build.gradle:**

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx.xxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        SPL {
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/droidpersistence.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/xstream-1.4.5.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.4.0'
    compile 'org.jdom:jdom2:2.0.6'
}
```

Comment: clean project and restart studio

Comment: Try to rebuild project and update gradle plugins for ksoap2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your build. gradle add this right before dependencies

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases"}
}
```

Then in your gradle upgrade to 3.6.0

```
compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.0'
```

Comment: Perfect!. Thank you very much. But add (mave{url...)  into (allprojects {
    repositories {) for run.

Comment: Thanks. The only solution that works after a day stuck with this.

Comment: @ÁlyssonAlexandre and Arthur Do you know why it not working in 4.4.2

Answer (score 0):

try to clean project first,
latest version is 3.6.0, try that too.

Comment: that is you can post in comment not in answer

Comment: when clean project show error: Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_SPLCompile'.
   > Could not find com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.0.

Comment: u can also download jar file and put it in lib directory . gradle and android studio cache for libs are still a little bit messy.